# Error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'koa'. 1 /// <reference types="koa" />

Tags: typescript

Seen in terminal when running `tsc --watch`:

```
node_modules/@shopify/koa-shopify-auth/dist/verify-request/verify-request.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'koa'.

1 /// <reference types="koa" />
```

I'm not clear why tsc is even reaching into `node_modules`. What is the proper fix for the above?

Searching this issue I have seen that users fixed a similar issue with another library by upgrading, but this was 2 years ago and not relevant now/with koa and/or next.js: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16772

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "allowJs" : false,
    "module" : "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop" : true,
    "types": [], // adding/removing this has not changed anything
    "target" : "es6",
    "sourceMap" : true,
    "noEmitOnError" : false,
    "jsx" : "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  },
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules", ".next", ".idea", "outputScripts"
  ]
  , "lib" : ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"]
}


// package.json
{
  "name": "shopify-node-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopify's node app for CLI tool",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-app.git"
  },
  "author": "Shopify Inc.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shopify/shopify-node-app/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^1.6.8",
    "@shopify/app-cli-node-generator-helper": "^1.1.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^3.1.41",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy": "^3.1.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks": "^2.0.0",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^3.21.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.1.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "koa": "^2.8.2",
    "koa-compose": "^4.1.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "koa-session": "^5.12.3",
    "next": "^9.1.1",
    "next-env": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "3.4.3",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.2.0",
    "husky": "^2.7.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.2"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,css,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the koa types npm package -> `npm install --save @types/koa`, usually when typescript / tslint complaines about types not installed it means you need to install the types package.
package source [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/koa)

Comment: I will keep that in mind, it has cleared the error, thank you

Comment: awesome im glad it helped!